# SSH EXEC not working to execute remote jar cmd

Tags: command-line, 18.04, ssh, remote

**What happened:**
I have entered `ssh root@ip nohup java -jar app.jar &` to run a jar on my remote server(the jar is an API server).
My local server is getting the jar logs instead of writing into nohup in the remote server and my jar is running but not working.

**Expected result:**
Able to  `SSH EXEC` run `nohup java -jar app.jar &` from my local system.

**Version:**
Ubuntu 18.04

**update:**
jar's API URL is returning the output only when jar cmd is executed via putty.
 For remote ssh exec, jar's API URL output is 404

**update 1:**
All I need is run the jar in the background in my remote server(exec the cmd from my local system).

Comment: Did you try it like this `ssh root@ip "nohup java -jar app.jar &"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remotely run a command on a ssh-server with a script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16050/remotely-run-a-command-on-a-ssh-server-with-a-script)

Comment: no adding " " is not working, still, the jar is returning logs to my local server instead of nohup @GeorgeUdosen

Answer (score 1):

`nohup` and console outputs...

The point is to redirect output to the null device.

```bsh
ssh user@host "sh -c 'cd /working/dir; nohup command -options > /dev/null 2>&1 &'"
# invoking sh makes output redirections easyier

ssh root@ip "sh -c 'nohup /path/to/java -jar /path/to/app.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &'"
```

Of course, output can be saved to a file

```bsh
nohup some_command > output.log 2>&1 &
```

---

**EDIT after comments**

- [X:expect Y:nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)
- [expect man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/expect.1.html)
- [more info about expect on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)

to automate connection via ssh then start a program and interact (as display output logs), `expect` could do the trick.

Install `expect` on your local machine

```bsh
sudo apt-get install expect
```

Create a small script, lets name it `startItUp.sh` and make it executable

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh user@host

# Its not recommended to insert a password in a script
# a good practice will be to copy key with ssh_copy_id
#expect "password: "
#send "myP@sswOrd\r"

# once ssh connection is enabled, lets expect for prompt
expect "$ "
# i got the prompt, i send a command
send "cd /go/to/needed/dir \r"

# again
expect "$ "
send "java -jar app.jar \r"

# let me interact (for example, i'll be able to ctrl+c)
interact
```

Comment: this stops me from getting logs back to my local server but my jar's API URL is returning 404 methods not found(the same jar works fine with normal cmd) @cmak.fr

Comment: @AATHITH RAJENDRAN, what means 'my local server'? If its related to output redirection, read the last line. About 404 and API URL, I dont understand the point, maybe because of the use of sh, try bash instead

Comment: sry, local server = local system. How can I use bash remote instead of ssh remote??

Comment: @AATHITH RAJENDRAN Oooh now its clearer : that was an XY... You do not want `nohup` but something like `expect` : You want to run a command (or a script) on your local machine which will start an ssh session and then run your Java prog. Ssh stays open and shows logs ?? If well understood, i will update my answser.

Comment: @pa4080 : thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting topic :)

First I thought, you must use single quotes in order to quote the remote command. Nice explanation, about this point, is provided by [@pt314](https://askubuntu.com/users/738593/pt314) within the accepted answer of the question [How can SSH work with an if condition?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1098053/566421) Here is the nonessential part:

> The main problem is that double-quoted strings are expanded by your
>   local shell...

But probably this is only a part of the problem. So before proceeding, let's say few words about the most canonical way of [`nohup`'s](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/nohup.1.html) usage that we can find on the Internet:

```bsh
nohup comand -options arguments >/path/to/log 2>&1 &
|     |                         |             |    # run 'nohup' in the background
|     |                         |             # redirect stderror to stdout
|     |                         # redirect stdout of 'nohup', /dev/null when don't need it
|     # the command to be executed, its stdout/err will be appended to the nohop's stdout
# run the following command detached from the current shell
```

According to the above, it looks you need a command like this:

```bsh
ssh user@host 'nohup remote_command -optins arguments &' >/tmp/local.log
```

*But, what actually happens here?*

The stdout (standard output) of `nohup` is attached to the ssh session and the output of the `ssh` command is redirected to a file, within the current shell session. In other words, the remote command is attached yo the local shell session. So if we kill something on the chain (the ssh session or the local shell) everything fails. Apparently, in this case, we do not need `nohup` on the remote session at all.

If we go one step further we can conclude that using `nohup` on the local side is a good idea:

```bsh
 nohup ssh user@host 'remote_command -optins arguments' >/tmp/local.log 2>&1 &
```

This looks much robust, but the execution of the remote command still depends on the ssh session initiated from the local computer, so if, for example, it is rebooted everything will fail again.

---

I think there is plenty of possible ways to achieve that you want in a more safer way. Here is one suggestion.

**1.** Let's use `nohup` in the *canonical way*  to execute the remote command:

```bsh
ssh user@host 'nohup remote_command -optins arguments >/tmp/remote.log 2>&1 &'
```

**2.** Fetch the remote log over ssh and write a local log in the background:

```bsh
nohup ssh user@host 'tail -n+1 -F /tmp/remote.log' >/tmp/local.log 2>&1 &
```

**3.** Monitor the local log file by:

```bsh
tail -F /tmp/local.log
```

Comment: hey @pa4080 `nohup java -jar app.jar server </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &` this cmd is working for me. how does this different from your answer??

Comment: Hi, @AATHITHRAJENDRAN, I'm not familiar with your particular jar program -- but what you are doing is: you are feeding its stdin from `</dev/null`, and apparently you do not need a log file, because you redirecting the stdout to `>/dev/null`. Please read about [/dev/null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device).

Comment: In addition you are redirecting the stdout `>/dev/null` on the remote instance, while in my answer it is redirected to a log file on the local instance... Is is not clear you are executing this command over ssh or directly within a shell on the remote machine...